# find biggest value field from table mysql

Tags: mysql, select

Would like to know , How do I find biggest value storing field from table .?
Table has 40 fields with string , would like to know which field has the biggest string..

Thanks

Comment: 'Biggest string' -  as in length or value?

Answer (score 0):

Run following query on each column.

`SELECT MAX(LENGTH(column_name)) FROM table_name;`

Comment: The question is to find the biggest string field among 40 fields.. I think it doesn't answer it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to find which field has biggest value. use information_schema.

Try this below exactly, and just replace your table name instead of yourtableName.

```
SELECT column_name, MAX(LENGTH(column_name)) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'yourtableName';
```